# `express` - sendFile throws error

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to develop a `express` application, in this I am getting error while I use this code :

```
  //allways sending the index file
  app.get('*', function( req, res ){

    res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));  

  })
```

here is the full code :

```
var

  express = require("express"),
  config = require('./server.config'),
  path  = require('path'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  app     = express();

  //setting static
  app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

  //connect to data base;
  mongoose.connect( config.database );

  //allways sending the index file
  app.get('*', function( req, res ){

    res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));  

  })


  app.listen( config.port );
  console.log( 'app started ' + config.port );
```

Any one help me to fix this. as well how to update the express in to latest?

[Live Demo](https://ide.c9.io/a3gwebtrain/myfamily)

error I am getting :

```
TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:18:9
    at callbacks (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at resume (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:60:7)
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:73:37)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:147:51)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:248:48)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:320:26
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:18:9
    at callbacks (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at resume (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:60:7)
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:73:37)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:147:51)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:248:48)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:320:26
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? The code looks ok especially the get part and sendfile.

Comment: see the console in the editor ( go live demo )

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have "c9" account.

Comment: @notionquest - error message added

Comment: Try change your route path to "/*".

Comment: If you are using express version 3.x, then please change the function to "res.sendfile" (i.e. lowercase 'f')

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using "express" version 3.x. The "sendfile" function was defined with lower case 'f' in express 3.x version.

You can either upgrade the express version (or) change the method name with lower case to fix this issue.

```
res.sendfile(path, [options], [fn]])
```